# EXAMPLE 6a Probability and a paradox sheldon ross

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I am studying from sheldon ross's first course in probability. I think this would be a silly question, but anyway I have to know the answer. This is from chapter 2.

**EXAMPLE 6a Probability and a paradox**

> Suppose that we possess an infinitely large urn and an infinite collection of balls labeled ball number 1, number 2, number 3, and so on. Consider an experiment performed as follows: At 1 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 1 through 10 are placed
> in the urn and a ball  is randomly selected and withdrawn. (Assume that the withdrawal taken no time.) At $\frac{1}{2}$ minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 11 through 20 are placed in the urn and a ball  is randomly selected and withdrawn among those present. At $\frac{1}{4}$ minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 21 through 30 are placed in the urn and a ball  is randomly selected and withdrawn among those present. At $\frac{1}{8}$ minute
> to 12 P.M., and so on. The question of interest is, How many balls are in the urn at 12 P.M.?

Now I understand the book solution of this question. Here is something I want to know

> Solution: We shall show that, with probability 1, the urn is empty at 12 P.M. Let us
> first consider ball number 1. Define $E_n$ to be the event that ball number 1 is still in the urn after the first n withdrawals have been made.

Now the book claims $E_n$ is a decreasing sequence. I want to know why?

Comment: I don't understand how the urn can be empty when you are putting in 10 balls in every time interval and withdrawing only 1 each time ??

Comment: @trueblueanil We put a countable amount in, and we withdrew a countable amount. There is a bijection between those amounts.

Comment: For, consider any ball—say, ball number n. At some time prior to 12 P.M. , this ball would have been withdrawn from the urn. Hence, for each n, ball number n is not in the urn at 12 P.M.; therefore, the urn must be empty at
that time.

Comment: @Alexander Isn’t $E_n$ decreasing just by definition? $E_{n+1}$ is a subset of $E_n$ since if the ball number $1$ is still in the urn after $n+1$ draws, then it surely was in the urn after $n$ draws. Once we remove a ball, we can’t put it back.

Comment: @Aig thanks man